# How do I change the height of a tabset on R Flexdashboard to be responsive?

Tags: css, r, flexdashboard

I have a row tabset and each tab contains a chart and a data table. However my data table keeps getting cut off. Is there some way to make the tabset height responsive so that my data table doesn't get cut off all the time?

See chart and data table cut off here:

[image: See chart and data table cut off here]

I know I could add a scrollbar using css but I don't exactly want that. I want my chart and data to show completely.

Comment: Which red redaction is the one being cut off? (It isn't clear to me from the image, perhaps you can explain a little better?)

Comment: The cut off is right at the bottom of the image. There is 1 filter box on the bottom left and right corners of the image. The chart displays fine just the data table is getting cut off. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be a solution to output your plots (if I see it correctly they are created with ggplot) with plottly.

```
library(plotly)

ggplotly(your_plot)
```